# Char-broil the [description] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [description](/questions/tagged/description) tag is a useless tag and should probably be outright killed.

The questions there aren't typically horrible to the point of deletion. Most have no votes, and have answers, so the tag could just be deleted.

Comment: It doesn't even have a description....Flambé it we shall

Comment: *Next on the list of verbs to use for burnination: Grill, Fry, Decimate and Killify*

Comment: *sigh*, [product _and_ description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640924/how-do-i-prevent-my-products-from-grabbing-the-product-description)

Answer (score 3):

Description:

[image: Burninated]

Comment: Shouldn't it say "this tag has been char-broiled"?

Comment: You're not a very good cook. I wanted medium-rare, and you gave me burninated. (Seriously, though, thank you!)