# Char-broil the [accept] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Looking at a question, I noticed an ambiguous tag:

> ### [accept](/questions/tagged/accept)

Here's a sampling of the questions there:

> [Will apple accept my app, even though it is more informational?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119153/will-apple-accept-my-app-even-though-it-is-more-informational)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116953/how-to-enforce-newlines-in-latex
>
> [Winsock - wait with calling accept() until client is really trying to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999503/winsock-wait-with-calling-accept-until-client-is-really-trying-to-connect)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987089/how-to-automatically-reconnect-the-device-to-the-bluetooth-server-socket-previou
>
> [Always print EAGAIN when calling accept after epoll_wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633392/always-print-eagain-when-calling-accept-after-epoll-wait)
>
> [Moving payments beyond pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500967/moving-payments-beyond-pending)

As you can see, there is absolutely *no* organization to this tag - it doesn't even have a tag wiki.

There are currently 128 of these - we could burninate it in less than a week if everyone pitched in.

### Let's burninate it.

Comment: You forgot [the signal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vbLqH.png)

Comment: +1 Char-broil... I prefer spatchcock and grill, but the result is the same.

Comment: [Do you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182727/char-broil-the-description-tag) happen to be [a mimic](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/images/alumni_mimic3rd.jpg)? ;] (kidding, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimic_%28Dungeons_%26_Dragons%29))

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I literally searched for other cooking words, but char-broil was the best I could think of.